# Intercept a Window Movement in C#

Tags: c#, windows, events

I'm working on a docking project, in which I need my form to dock itself into a window that doesn't belong to my application. I have no problem detecting the location of the window, however I haven't got a clue on how to intercept the event of movement of the window. Does anyone know how can I intercept the event of movement of a window?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327691/globally-intercept-window-movement) post will give you some clues.

An alternative way (but not very nice) would be to have a timer that fires every 500 milisecs and checks each time for window position and compare with the previous one. Then if different adjust your window accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Listening for window messages requires injecting code in the process whose window you want to dock to.  You cannot inject C# code, you can't reliably get the CLR initialized in that process.  You'll only have a fighting chance if you use native code.  Google EasyHook.  Black belt Win32 API skills are required to bring this to a good end.